# Group Words dynamically using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

Is there a way to dynamically group words using regex?

I have this code in c#

```
string strRegex = @"(?<=\d+)(.*)(?=md\.?)";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
string strTargetString = @"2 Elizabeth                        Winslow                           md. Gilbert                             Brooks";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    Debug.WriteLine(myMatch.Value);      
  }
}
```

This is my sample text

```
    2 Elizabeth                        Winslow                          md. Gilbert                             Brooks
8 Rebekah Gulliver Stall                                              md. George Leonard Dary
```

This is my sample output

```
Fname: Elizabeth : Index: 7
Lname: Winslow : Index: 40
Fname: Rebekah Gulliver : Index: 3
LName: Stall : Index: 20
```

In my code i can only get the text between the `number` and the word `md.`

If i'm going to split the words. I can't get the index of the words.

Is it possible to dynamically group this words using Regex?

Or another work around to get the text and the index of this?

Comment: The fastest way I can think of will be scan the string (index 0 to end) and  Identify the FName/LName pairs... The loop iteration variable will be the index. That will be about O(n)

Comment: if you are able to split the words properly, just use String.IndexOf('word') to get the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following regex solution:

```
var s = "    2 Elizabeth                        Winslow                          md. Gilbert                             Brooks";
var result = Regex.Matches(s, @"\d\s+(?<FName>.*?)\s+(?<LName>\S+)\s*md\b")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => new {
            FName = m.Groups["FName"].Value, 
            FIndex = m.Groups["FName"].Index+1,
            LName = m.Groups["LName"].Value,
            LIndex = m.Groups["LName"].Index+1
        }).ToList();
foreach (var pair in result)
    Console.WriteLine($"{pair.FName} : {pair.FIndex} : {pair.LName} : {pair.LIndex}");
// => Elizabeth : 7 : Winslow : 40
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/fut1Zb)

The regex is

```
\d\s+(?<FName>.*?)\s+(?<LName>\S+)\s*md\b
```

See [its online demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cd%5cs%2b%28%3f%3cFName%3e.*%3f%29%5cs%2b%28%3f%3cLName%3e%5cS%2b%29%5cs*md%5cb&i=++++2+Elizabeth++++++++++++++++++++++++Winslow++++++++++++++++++++++++++md.+Gilbert+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Brooks%0d%0a8+Rebekah+Gulliver+Stall++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++md.+George+Leonard+Dary).

**Details**

- `\d` - a digit
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `(?<FName>.*?)` - Group "FName": any 0+ chars other than a newline, as few as possible
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `(?<LName>\S+)` - Group "LName": any 0+ chars other than whitespace, as many as possible
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `md\b` - a whole word `md` (`\b` is a word boundary)

Comment: I've been looking for a solution for a while and your answer didn't just answer my question but you also provide me a brief detail about the solution you provided. Thank you so much. Hopefully there are lots of you here in stackoverflow